# How to get current element in WPF datagrid and how to do something with it?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, icommand, commandparameter

Some time ago I began to study the MVVM pattern with this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165368/WPF-MVVM-Quick-Start-Tutorial). I use MicroMvvm.

I have a WPF project with EntityFramework model. I wrote ViewModels and XAML views.
I want to display my data in a DataGrid.(2 columns with data and 2 buttoncolumn: Edit, Delete)

```xml
<DataGrid Height="250" ItemsSource="{Binding Books}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DeleteTemplate" >
            <Button x:Name="DeleteButton" Command="{Binding DeleteBook, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding}" >Delete</Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Title}"  Header="Book"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Author}"  Header="Author"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn  CellTemplate="{StaticResource EditTemplate}" Header="Редактировать"/>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn  CellTemplate="{StaticResource DeleteTemplate}" Header="Удалить"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In my LibraryViewModel.cs

```cs
#region Commands
void DeleteBookExecute()
{
    if (_books == null)
        return;

    //MessageBox.Show("This is delete button. Delete item id:" myMysticalObjectFromCommandParameter );
}
bool CanDeleteBookExecute()
{
    return true;
}
public ICommand DeleteBook
{
    get
    {
        return new RelayCommand(DeleteBookExecute, CanDeleteBookExecute);
    }
}
```

When I press the buttons (delete/edit) I want to to delete/edit the current object.
I don't know how to do it in MVVM.

Can I do it with `Command="{Binding DeleteBook, Mode=OneWay}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"`?

If it's correct, how I can get the data from `CommandParameter` in my LibraryViewModel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As DHN says, your command execution methods `DeleteBookExecute()`, `CanDeleteBookExecute()` should have a parameter of type object.

You're ideas are pointing in the right direction. Try this:

```
<DataGrid Name="LibraryGrid"
          Height="250" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Books}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
```

and

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteBook, ElementName=LibraryGrid}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"
```

The use of `ElementName` with the `DataContext.DeleteBook` gets you the Command of the LibraryViewModel.

Comment: i don't understand how I can take this object in LibraryViewModel.cs: 
        void DeleteBookExecute()
        {?}.
rewrite this method in that manner? void DeleteBookExecute(object param)
and param will have my row object? or not...

Comment: @chromigo: That should be it, yes. The parameter gets passed automatically by WPF magic...

Comment: Thanks for help. When I change MicroMvvm methods (take 1 param, as DHN says) evrything worked.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit curious that your command methods have no parameters. I would expect them to look like this

```
void DoSomething(object param) {}
bool CanDoSomething(object param) {}
```

Nevertheless, I would bind the `SelectedItem` property of the `DataGrid` to a property on the VM. For some more information, pls have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.selecteditem%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource={Binding Books} SelectedItem={Binding SelectedBook} />
```

So you can easily access the 'current' item in your commands.

Hope this helps a bit.